# insert command SQL server -identity Pkey autoincrement - column name by type , in "where condition"

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert-update, identity-column

i would like to alter a stored procedure so i will not suplly the `identity` column name

```
INSERT INTO tablName ..... WHERE IDENTITY_Column = 10
```

can i tell sql server managment studio to just refer to the `IDENTITY` column so it will find 
it by its type which is (at least in my tables a default) autoincremet PK ID type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is related to a table copy trick i was trying to pull via stored procedure.

```
USE [YourDataBaseName]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Utils_TableRowCopy]    Script Date: 10/03/2012 18:26:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Utils_TableRowCopy](
    @TableName VARCHAR(50) ,
    @RowNumberToCopy INT
)



AS
BEGIN


declare @RowIdentity sysname =
(
 SELECT name FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE object_id = object_id(@TableName)
)

    DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(5000), @query VARCHAR(8000);
    SET @query = '' ;

    SELECT @columns =
        CASE
            WHEN @columns IS NULL THEN column_name
            ELSE @columns + ',' + column_name
        END
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE (
        TABLE_NAME = LTRIM(RTRIM(@TableName))
        AND
        column_name <> LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowIdentity))
    );

    SET @query = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' (' + @columns + ') SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @RowIdentity + ' = ' + CAST(@RowNumberToCopy AS VARCHAR);

    --SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    declare  @query2 VARCHAR(100) =  ' Select Top 1 * FROM '+ @TableName +' Order BY ' + @RowIdentity + ' desc' ;
    EXEC (@query);
    EXEC (@query2);
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't really given enough code for us to see what you are trying to do but from the snippet in the question.

```
WHERE IDENTITY_Column = 10
```

You can just use

```
WHERE $IDENTITY = 10
```

for that (to filter against an identity column without specifying the name).

If you do actually need to lookup the column name then an easier way, avoiding deprecated views is

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.identity_columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('dbo.YourTable')
```

Comment: i did chanage my longer verstion of `select` to your version so it works aswell . thanks for that comment.

Comment: i added a new answer so you could know what i was getting to , i'll bee happy if you could show a shorter / more elegance version

Answer (score 1):

found this information by now .

that is the plain and simple version .

```
declare @tblName sysname = '______'--<== enter a table name

declare @NameOfIDColumn sysname =
(
SELECT Name 
FROM syscolumns
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY( id ,name, 'IsIdentity') = 1 and OBJECT_NAME(id)= @tblName )

select  @NameOfIDColumn   AS 'result'
```

you could add this as an option to display last row of a table soretd by its record#

```
declare  @query VARCHAR(100) =  'Select Top 1 * FROM '+ @tblName +' Order BY ' + @IdentColumnName + ' desc' ;
EXEC (@query);
```

and to play around or even make it as a test page in a .net project 
make this one as a stored proc that will outpout a message to a test page .

```
declare @tblName sysname = '______'--<== enter a table name

declare @IdentColumnName sysname =
(
SELECT Name 
FROM syscolumns
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY( id ,name, 'IsIdentity') = 1 and OBJECT_NAME(id)= @tblName )
declare @result VARCHAR (50) = @tblName + ' Identity Column is ' + @IdentColumnName;
select  @result   AS 'result'
```

and with a shorter version of "idntity column search", by *Martin Smith*

```
declare @tblName sysname = '______'--<== enter a table name

declare @IdentColumnName sysname =
(SELECT name FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE object_id = object_id(@TableName))
declare @result VARCHAR (50) = @tblName + ' Identity Column is ' + @IdentColumnName;
select  @result   AS 'result'
```